# Linked list .clear() method not working properly

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have to make my own double linked list. I'm a beginner, so please forgive me my lack of knowledge. This list has to implement the List java interface, so I have a remove(int), a remove(Object), and a clear() method too, of which the clear() method does not do it's work, meaning it does not remove all elements of the list, only some.

Here is the clear() method:

```
public void clear() {
    for (T t : this) {
        this.remove(t);
    }
    this.remove(this.size);
}
```

The remove(Object)  method:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (this.indexOf(o) >= 0){
        remove(this.indexOf(o));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And finally, the remove(int) method:

```
public T remove(int index) {
    if (getNode(index) == null || this.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else if (this.size == 1){
        this.size = 0;
        Node<T> currentNode = this.firstNode;
        this.firstNode = null;
        this.lastNode = null;
        return currentNode.data;
    }

    Node<T> currentNode = this.getNode(index);

    if (currentNode.nextNode != null){
        if (currentNode.previousNode != null){
            currentNode.previousNode.nextNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        } else {
            this.firstNode = currentNode.nextNode;
            this.firstNode.previousNode = null;
            this.size--;
            return currentNode.data;
        }
    }
    if (currentNode.previousNode != null){
        if (currentNode.nextNode != null) {
            currentNode.nextNode.previousNode = currentNode.previousNode;
        } else {
            this.lastNode = currentNode.previousNode;
            this.lastNode.nextNode = null;
            this.size--;
            return currentNode.data;
        }
    }
    currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
    this.size--;

    for(int i = index; i < this.size-1; i++){
        currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        currentNode.index--;
    }

    return currentNode.data;
}
```

Please not only point out the place of the bug, but also help me improve this code, if you can. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: `for (T t : this) {
        this.remove(t);
    }` is totally messing with the enumerator. use a `for (int i = size()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {}` loop instead

Comment: as @njzk2 mentioned, your code throws `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are trying to iterate over a list while you are removing the items

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you. Although, if you see any more problems, create an answer including this, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `clear()` method is very suspicious in that it removes an element from the `List` while that list is being iterated.  If you tried to do that with one of the built-in `List` implementations you would get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  It's actually fairly hard to implement a `List` that can handle that sort of thing correctly.

In any case, I would normally expect the `clear()` method of a Java linked list to simply nullify the list's references to any nodes, just as your `remove(int)` method does when removing the only element of your list.  `clear()` should be able to do the same, without regard for the list's contents.

*Edited to add:*

Specifically, since you asked, it looks like you could use

```
public void clear() {
    this.firstNode = null;
    this.lastNode = null;
    this.size = 0;
}
```

(Use of `this.` is unnecessary, and I wouldn't normally do it, but I'm following the style of your other code.)  Note that I do not have enough information to be certain that this is 100% correct and sufficient for your implementation, which is why I did not initially include specific code.

Comment: `clear() { while (!isEmpty()) { remove(0); } }`

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, that's better than iterating backwards by index, but not as good as `clear() { firstNode = null; lastNode = null; size = 0; }`.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. I will wait for a bit in case anyone would post a more detailed answer, but then I will accept this.

Comment: I merely wanted to give the correct version of his code's intention. That I do that here, is entirely as follower of your answer. In general I advise giving some code, as you just did.